# How to run an access macro via excel VBA on a database which is currently open?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am setting up a vba code that runs a macro of an access database. 
The code I am starting from is the following:

```
Sub import()
Dim appAccess As Object
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("database link")
appAccess.UserControl = True
appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro name"
End Sub
```

In this case the database get opened and the macro runs but I would just need the macro to run on the already open database.

Thank you

Comment: *the database get opened and the macro runs but I would just need the macro to run on the already open database* Sorry, but could you please be more specific? What means *run the macro on the opened database*? Do you have 2 databases opened and want to run the macro od DB1 into DB2?

Comment: By open you mean a connection open by another macro? You could setup your variables as global, and reuse them from either macro (provided you make sure they are initialised first).

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns The database is already open. I would need a way to activate it so that I can run the access macros via vba code in excel

Comment: But you said *the macro runs*, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From a code module you can simply

```
DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro name"
```

Which will execute in the current database

If you are trying to do this from another application (such as Excel) you can

```
Dim accApp As Access.Application
Set accApp = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
```

but you should then check

```
accApp.CurrentDb.Name
```

to make sure you are looking at the correct database

(Having said that, if you are wanting to manipulate data in the database there are better ways of doing that using ADO or DAO.  The above will work but will never be very stable).